# proving unsatisfiability in a union of closed WFF

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If I am given a closed set of wff $X$ and it is *unsatisfiable*, then how do I show that the set $X \cup \{A\}$, where $A$ is any closed wff, is *unsatisfiable*?

Comment: Please, it is not "a closed set of wff" but "a set of closed wff" ...

Comment: Basically, saying that $X$ is *unsat* means that there is **no** way to interpret the "non-logical" symbols in some non-empty domain $\mathcal D$ such that, for all $\varphi \in X$, we have that $\varphi$ is true in $\mathcal D$. If so, "adding" to $X$ a new formula $A$ can never "affect" the above "impossibility" ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be unsatisfiable. Then, by compactness, there is a finite subset $Y$ of $X$ that is unsatisfiable. Since $Y \subseteq X \cup \{A\}$, then it follows that $X \cup \{A\}$ is also unsatisfiable.